# CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is deprecated in iOS 9, how do I use "stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR(";:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Xcode says it is deprecated in iOS 9. So, how do I use stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this

```
NSString *value = @"<url>";
value = [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Careful, `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` contains the `+` character, so this char won't be encoded. However, the + character has a special meaning, it means SPACE, so when you encode `test+test` that way, it won't be encoded at all but at the server side, this is decoded to `test test`.

Comment: @Mecki so how to exclude the `+` from the allowed character set? Maybe `removeCharactersInString:@"+"` could be used to exclude `+` from this charset.

Comment: @loretoparisi I usually do it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39371482/15809 After all there are very little chars you absolutely have to encode, yet you may encode all characters if you like.

Comment: This solution works for me, @"nav+nav;nav/nav?nav:nav$nav nav"  = nav+nav;nav/nav?nav:nav$nav%20nav .

Answer (score 18):

The character set `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` contains all characters allowed in the query part of the URL (`..?key1=value1&key2=value2`) and is not limited to characters allowed in **keys and values** of such a query. E.g. `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` contains `&` and `+`, as these are of course allowed in query (`&` separates the key/value pairs and `+` means space), but they are not allowed in a **key** or a **value** of such a query.

Consider this code:

```
NSString * key = "my&name";
NSString * value = "test+test";
NSString * safeKey= [key 
     stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
         [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]
];
NSString * safeValue= [value
     stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
         [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]
];
NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", safeKey, safeValue];
```

`query` will be `?my&name=test+test`, which is totally wrong. It defines a key named `my` that has no value and a key named `name` whose value is `test test` (+ means space!).

The correct query would have been `?my%26name=test%2Btest`.

As long as you only deal with ASCII strings or as long as the server can deal with UTF-8 characters in the URL (most web servers today do that), the number of chars you absolutely have to encode is actually rather small and very constant. Just try that code:

```
NSCharacterSet * queryKVSet = [NSCharacterSet
    characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":/?&=;+!@#$()',*% "
].invertedSet;

NSString * value = ...;
NSString * valueSafe = [value
    stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:queryKVSet
];
```

Comment: Does not encode spaces, % and other characters. The safest way is to start  with `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` and remove characters not allowed in keys and values, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790833/3046117).

Answer (score 8):

Another solution to encode those characters allowed in `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet` but not allowed in a key or a value (e.g.: `+`):

```
- (NSString *)encodeByAddingPercentEscapes {
    NSMutableCharacterSet *charset = [[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
    [charset removeCharactersInString:@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"];
    NSString *encodedValue = [self stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:charset];
    return encodedValue;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to remove `#`, `%`, `[`, `]` (generally unsafe and not part of `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`).